# Typo3 won't connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, content-management-system, typo3

Just installed Typo3 Version 6, Government package on Linux Mint 14. Installed latest version of PHP & MYSQL. Compiled PHP with:

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql  --with-openssl --with-zlib --enable-soap --enable-hash --with-pcre-regex --with-curl --with-gd --with-mysqlih-mysql  --with-openssl --with-zlib --enable-soap

make

make install
```

Typo3 installer gives the following error:

> *There is no connection to the database!
>
>   (Username: typo3, Host: localhost, Using Password: YES)
>
>   Go to Step 1 and enter a valid username and password!*

The username and password that I entered are correct. I am able to connect to mysql using these credentials with

1. phpMyAdmin web interface
2. mysql -u typo3 -p typo3db

Did Google search and found some people had this problem and the cause was one of the three things:

1. underscore in DB name - as up can see by my db name, it doesn't apply to my case
2. config not allowing persistent connections to mysql - doesn't apply to my case,since I am currently allowing persistent connections.
3. permissions of typo3 files - suggested fix was set all files to 755 or 777 (way to permissive in my opinion), but I tried this to rule out permission issue. Didn't resolve the issue in my case.

I enabled general logging for mysql. When I enter username and password for mysql user in the typo3 installer, it immediately gives the error that it can't connect, but mysql logs show no login attempt. Conversely, when I login with phpMyAdmin it does show the success and when I type in a wrong password on purpose, the log shows it is being denied.

This all implies to me that no connection from Typo3 to mysql is being initiated, but I don't now why.

Any thoughts on what the issue could be or what I should check next?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, but found I had to use the server IP address and not localhost. Odd that localhost has always worked in the past without issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem.
Fixed it by enabling required modules in PHP.
They are listed in the INSTALL.txt file in the root TYPO3 folder.

```
- fileinfo
- filter
- GD2
- JSON
- mysqli
- openssl
- pcre
- session
- SOAP
- SPL
- standard
- xml
- zlib
```

I believe the crucial module in this case was mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

marc_s,

Did you check your files permissions ?

For TYPO3 I use these command from TYPO3 installation folder :

```
find . -type d ! -name .svn -exec chmod 755 {} \; && find . -type f ! -name .svn -exec chmod 644 {} \;

chmod -R g+wX fileadmin typo3temp typo3conf uploads
```

You can also this a article :
http://dmitry-dulepov.com/article/migrating-typo3-installation-to-a-different-server.html

I hope this information will help.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is this:
The file access rights to /var/lib/mysql must be set in this manner:

```
[root@localhost phpmyadmin]# cd /var/lib
[root@localhost lib]# chmod 755 mysql
[root@localhost lib]# ls -ld mysql
drwxr-xr-x 16 mysql mysql 4096 Dez 16 20:14 mysql/
```

The mysql user and mysql group must be set also in all files and folders under /var/lib/mysql.
After this change I could login to the TYPO3 database using the Install Tool.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptom with typo3 4.6, its installer didn't connect. I traced this down to this callstack:

class.ux_t3lib_db.php / sql_pconnect / handler_init

The handler_init function has this code:

```
        if (!$cfgArray['config']['database']) {
            // Configuration is incomplete
            return;
        }
```

The database property was empty. I had to set it in the localconf.php with this line $typo_db = "mydatabasename";

I also created my database with this name in MySQL.